# Android video displayed wrong in specific portrait rotation

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am using a [Geniatech ATV1220](http://www.geniatech.com/pa/atv1220.asp) running Android 4.2.2 to display a video in a simple `VideoView`. It is connected to a monitor via the HDMI port. For my setup I need to display content in different orientations. It all works fine in 3 of the 4 orientations (Landscape, Landscape flipped, Portrait flipped). In Portrait the video is displayed wrong though.

I created a basic application to reproduce this behaviour. (https://github.com/IngoAlbers/SimpleVideoView)

The relevant parts:

**VideoViewActivity**

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);

    final VideoView videoView =
        (VideoView) findViewById(com.ingoalbers.simplevideoview.R.id.videoView);

    assert videoView != null;
    videoView.setVideoPath("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4");
    videoView.start();
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.ingoalbers.simplevideoview">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**activity_video_view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.ingoalbers.simplevideoview.VideoViewActivity">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Portrait flipped**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

**Portrait**

[image]

As you can see in Portrait mode the video is played but is only using 50% of the screen width and seems to be stretched in the height so you cannot see the whole video.

I had the same behaviour in a `TextureView` and `SurfaceView`. So I think the problem is related to the `MediaPlayer`. I also changed the `android:background` property of the `VideoView` to be red and I saw that the actual dimensions of the `VideoView` were correct.

This is probably a system or hardware related problem, but I might also be able to solve it in a programmatic way, as other applications, like the default VideoPlayer application don't suffer from this behaviour.

It should also be possible for me to change system settings, etc. I will be happy to provide any additional information and files that might be needed to solve this issue.

**Update**:

I was able to reproduce the problem using [MXPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad). **But** when I switched from HW to SW decoding it was rendered correctly. Also there was no vertical stretching of the video even with HW decoding, but it still only showed 50% of the width.

**Update #2**:

When I turn on "Show surface updates" in developer options only half of the screen where the video is displayed is flashing in Portrait mode. In the 3 other orientations the whole screen is flashing.

**Portrait flipped**

[image]

**Portrait**

[image]

Additionally I uploaded the system [VideoPlayer.apk](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzA08cS2_h09QUlvTzNiU1pRRGc), which can play the video correctly, if it might help anyone.